# Google GPT returns empty ads under which conditions

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-ads-script, google-publisher-tag

I have Google Ads integration in my NextJS app, but every now and then when I try to define a slot and load ad in it I get `event.isEmpty = true` for `"slotRenderedEvent"`.

I see GPT documentation has mentioned this field [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.events.SlotRenderEndedEvent_isEmpty), but it does not explains uder what circumstances GPT might return `isEmpty` as `true`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: isEmpty means that ads was not rendered. (it is mantion this in docs) probably you don't fulfilled ads requirements and it decided to not render ad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isEmpty=true means the adserver was not able to select an ad to display on this request. Different reasons to explain the lack of ad to show :

- no campaign / line item is currently live on your ad network.
- a campaign is live, but due to the fact that the adserver is trying to distribute impressions evenly over time, it may be "on hold" for few minutes (or more). Details [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/2669484?hl=en).
- campaigns are live, but none is targeting the requested inventory (adunit, device, country, daytime...etc). Details [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9860806?hl=en&ref_topic=7506394).
- campaigns are live, but they all have a "frequency capping" that your browser reached. It is usually set to limit the number of exposure to each user. Details [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/82242?hl=en&ref_topic=7506394).
- no house ad is live on your network : this kind of campaign is meant to fullfill the "empty" spaces so no "blank" adrequests should happens. Details [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/79305?hl=en).

Following [this](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/1739296?hl=en) documentation, you should be able to identify the reasons why the adrequest is returning nothing to display.

To avoid empty spaces, you can ask the adOps team to activate an house ad priorty campaign which will be called every time no "guaranteed" ad is available.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so I am guessing nothing on my implementation is causing it right? because I have seen situations where GPT will not even respond bad if I manipulate the div in any way after issuing the request to load ad in a slot

Comment: from my experience, if you have an ad displayed and you move the div related ad slot, the ad will disappear, but your event will still return that an ad was selected. The fact that the moved ad is not anymore displayed is a problem. That is why google does not recommend you to move divs after the adcalls were done. See here : https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/common_implementation_mistakes#scenario-7:-moving-slot-containers-within-the-dom-after-calling-display
It is a "mistake" according to their documentation.

Comment: right but I'm not moving ads anymore, one one source libs were doing it because of which we were not receiving slotRendered response from google at all, now we're getting that event but with isEmpty: true, so I'm no longer manupulating ad div and I'm also getting slotRendered event for all slotRequest but more often I'm getting isEmpty: true

Comment: allright, so your adrequests are not filled ;) ask your ad operation manager to activate line items and you should be fine.